# Drawing rectangle within the loop?

Tags: java, swing, awt, draw

I'm trying to animate a rectangle based on a coordinate determined by for-loop, inside a button. Here is my `JComponent` Class:

```
public class Rect extends JComponent {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int w;
    public int h;
    
    public Rect (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2.setColor(Color.green);
        g2.drawRect(x+15, y+15, w, h);
    }
}
```

and here is my button and `button` inside `JFrame` class:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    Rect R = new Rect(15, 15, 50, 50);
    JPanel lm = new JPanel();
    LayoutManager lay = new OverlayLayout(lm);
    JButton animate = new JButton("animate");

    public MainFrame () {
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        lm.setLayout(lay);
        lm.add(R);
}
    animate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
               for (int k = 0; k < 500; k+=50) {
                R = new Rect(k, k, 50, 50);
               validate();
               repaint();
               }
           }   
  });
}
```

But when I run the code and click the button, nothing happens. What's wrong?

EDIT: I run the frame inside my main class like this:

```
public class OrImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
                mf.setVisible(true);
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

Comment: Class `MainFrame` does not compile. What is `sg`?

Comment: @Abra I've updated the code. I run the `MainFrame` by using main method in other class. I've deleted the `sg`

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like your `MainFrame` class still does not compile, even after your edit.

Comment: Animation in Swing is like manual animation.  You create a series of still images that you change (repaint) quickly.  Your drawing JPanel should draw an image based on the contents of a logical model.  The values in the logical model are changed with a Swing Timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code of class `MainFrame` such that when you press the `animate` button, *something* happens, but I don't know if that is what you want to happen.

I did not change class `Rect` and I added `main()` method to `MainFrame` just to keep everything in one class.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    Rect R = new Rect(15, 15, 50, 50);
    JPanel lm = new JPanel();
    LayoutManager lay = new OverlayLayout(lm);
    JButton animate = new JButton("animate");

    public MainFrame () {
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        lm.setLayout(lay);
        lm.add(R);
        animate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                for (int k = 0; k < 500; k+=50) {
                    R = new Rect(k, k, 50, 50);
                    lm.add(R);
                }
                lm.revalidate();
                lm.repaint();
            }   
        });
        add(lm, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(animate, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new MainFrame());
    }
}
```

The main change is in method `actionPerformed()`. You need to add `R` to the `JPanel`. You need to call `revalidate()` on the `JPanel` because you have changed the number of components that it contains. And after calling `revalidate()` you should call `repaint()` (again, on the `JPanel`) to make it redraw itself.

This is how it looks before pressing `animate`.

[image: before]

And this is how it looks after pressing `animate`

[image: after]

### EDIT

As requested – with animation.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    Rect R = new Rect(15, 15, 50, 50);
    JPanel lm = new JPanel();
    LayoutManager lay = new OverlayLayout(lm);
    JButton animate = new JButton("animate");
    private int  x;
    private int  y;
    private Timer  timer;

    public MainFrame () {
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        lm.setLayout(lay);
        lm.add(R);
        timer = new Timer(500, event -> {
            if (x < 500) {
                lm.remove(R);
                x += 50;
                y += 50;
                R = new Rect(x, y, 50, 50);
                lm.add(R);
                lm.revalidate();
                lm.repaint();
            }
            else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        animate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.start();
            }   
        });
        add(lm, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(animate, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new MainFrame());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the correction. Actually, my codes are quite long so I needed to declutter a lot before I post here. Your demonstration is just exactly what I have in mind, but I wonder is there any way so that I don't have to add `R` to the `panel` inside every loop? Because I just want to make the rectangle move, not multiplying.

Comment: @RainhardCalvin For animation in _Swing_ you should use a [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: I thought Swing Timer is just for add the delay before a task and after another. Perhaps I can delete or dispose the rectangle after every loop to make it looks animated?

Comment: If I may, there's one thing still boggling me; in my full code the for loop is in another `class`. So I wanted to just call that `class`'s method inside the button and I put the `add`, `revalidate`, and `repaint` inside that loop by `MainFrame mf = new Mainframe();` then `mf.lm.add(R)`, `mf.lm.revalidate();`, `mf.lm.repaint();`, but nothing happened. Is my code wrong?

Comment: @RainhardCalvin if you want help debugging your code, then either post a new question or [edit] the code in your question, above. In either case, make sure you post a [mcve].

Comment: I just post a New Question. Thank you 