# Can't repaint JPanel from another class

Tags: java, swing, awt, draw

Following my previous Question about [Drawing rectangle within the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925307/drawing-rectangle-within-the-loop/64925610?noredirect=1#comment114788158_64925610)

Now I want to draw the Rectangle from another class, inside the for-loop. Here is the class of the loop:

```
public class FaceDetect extends SwingWorker {
    
    IntegralCalc3 ic3 = new IntegralCalc3();
    MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
  
    Rectangle R;

       protected FaceDetect doInBackground() throws Exception {
       //Initial width and height is 60, 60
       outerloop:
       for(int w = 50; w <= ic3.integral.length && w <= ic3.integral[0].length; w = (int) Math.round(w*1.2)  ) {  
            int h = w;

            for(int x = 0; x <= ic3.integral.length-w; x+=5 ) { 
            for(int y = 0; y <= ic3.integral[0].length-w; y+=5 ) {
            
             R = new Rectangle (x, y, w, h);
             mf.lm.add(R);
             mf.lm.revalidate();
             mf.lm.repaint();
            } 
            }             
        } 
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is my rectangle class:

```
public class Rect extends JComponent {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int w;
    public int h;
    
    public Rect (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2.setColor(Color.green);
        g2.drawRect(x+15, y+15, w, h);
    }
}
```

And finally here is my button inside the JFrame class:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    Rect R = new Rect(15, 15, 50, 50);
    JPanel lm = new JPanel();
    LayoutManager lay = new OverlayLayout(lm);
    JButton animate = new JButton("animate");

    public MainFrame () {
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        lm.setLayout(lay);
        lm.add(R);
}
        animate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
               try {   
               new FaceDetect().execute();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
               }   
      });

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new MainFrame());
        }
    }
```

But nothing happened when I click the `animate` button. Where is the flaw of my codes?

Comment: You **must** call method `repaint()` on the _Event Dispatch Thread_ (EDT). Method `doInBackground()` does **not** run on the EDT. Refer to [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the flaw of my codes?

You create an instance of the MainFrame in your main() method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new MainFrame());
    }
}
```

Then you create another instance in your FaceDetect class:

```
public class FaceDetect extends SwingWorker {
    IntegralCalc3 ic3 = new IntegralCalc3();
    MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
```

You can't just keep creating new instances of an object. You need to pass a reference of the MainFrame class to the FaceDetect class.

However I would suggest that is still not the proper design since your SwingWorker logic is incorrect. You are using the SwingWorker incorrectly! The `doInBackground` logic should NOT update the state of the Swing component!

> Following my previous question...

The suggestion was to use a `Swing Timer` for animation. That is how your code should be designed. All the Swing Timer does is generate an event at a regular interval. You then respond to the event.

So in your case you would want to create a `move()` method in your Rect class, which would update the x/y location and repaint() the component. The logic for the Timer would be to simply invoke the `move()` method.

See: [How to make JScrollPane (In BorderLayout, containing JPanel) smoothly autoscroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907207/how-to-make-jscrollpane-in-borderlayout-containing-jpanel-smoothly-autoscroll/33907282#33907282) for a basic example of using a Swing Timer.

Comment: So I need to change my `FaceDetect` class from implementing `Swing Worker` to `Swing Timer`, and then call the `move()` method inside the for-loop?